# MySQL Advanced Sum Queries

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+
| TaxAuthority | Effective  | AuthTaxRate |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
| city1        | 1993-01-01 |         1.0 |
| city1        | 1994-01-01 |         1.5 |
| city2        | 1993-09-01 |         1.5 |
| city2        | 1994-01-01 |         2.0 |
| city2        | 1995-01-01 |         2.5 |
| city3        | 1993-01-01 |         1.9 |
| city3        | 1993-07-01 |         2.3 |
| county1      | 1993-01-01 |         2.3 |
| county1      | 1994-10-01 |         2.5 |
| county1      | 1995-01-01 |         2.7 |
| county2      | 1993-01-01 |         2.4 |
| county2      | 1994-01-01 |         2.7 |
| county2      | 1995-01-01 |         2.8 |
| state1       | 1993-01-01 |         0.5 |
| state1       | 1994-01-01 |         0.8 |
| state1       | 1994-07-01 |         0.9 |
| state1       | 1994-10-01 |         1.1 |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to select the tax rate for city2 on Nov 1 1994.  Example:

```
City2 = 2.0
County1=2.5
State1=1.1
Total=5.6
```

So far, I have been able to get all the amount that add up to the 5.6; however, I do not know how to add up the 3 sums.  This is the statement I have so far:

```
    select AuthTaxRate 
    from TaxRates 
    where TaxAuthority = 'City2' 
    and Effective <= '1994-11-01' 
    and Effective > '1993-09-01' 
    union 
    select AuthTaxRate 
    from TaxRates 
    where TaxAuthority = 'County1' 
    and Effective <= '1994-11-01' 
    and Effective > '1993-09-01' 
    union 
    select AuthTaxRate 
    from TaxRates 
    where TaxAuthority = 'State1' 
    and Effective <= '1994-11-01' 
    and Effective > '1994-07-01';
```

The result of my statement is:

```
+-------------+
| AuthTaxRate |
+-------------+
|         2.0 |
|         2.5 |
|         1.1 |
+-------------+
```

Does anyone know how to add up these values?

Comment: `Select sum(AuthTaxRate)from TaxRates...`

Comment: er - how do you know which city is in which county? (and what about cities that span multiple counties)

Answer (score 0):

I am now sure but you can try like this-

```
Select sum( 
 select AuthTaxRate 
    from TaxRates 
    where TaxAuthority = 'City2' 
    and Effective <= '1994-11-01' 
    and Effective > '1993-09-01' 
    union 
    select AuthTaxRate 
    from TaxRates 
    where TaxAuthority = 'County1' 
    and Effective <= '1994-11-01' 
    and Effective > '1993-09-01' 
    union 
    select AuthTaxRate 
    from TaxRates 
    where TaxAuthority = 'State1' 
    and Effective <= '1994-11-01' 
    and Effective > '1994-07-01';
 ) As  total;
```